# What is Linux service/daemon file logging best practice apart from syslog?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

I think syslog is really a good choice for service.

Besides syslog, is there any other file logging best practice ?

Is writing file to `/tmp` or `/var/log` directly appropriate?

Comment: Many services do directly write log files.  Just about all of them allow you to change the log path with a command-line argument.  The language you write the service in has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Read [logging best practice](https://www.google.com/search?q=logging+best+practice). Questions with risk to attract too opinionated answers will be closed.

> Is writing file to `/tmp` or `/var/log` directly <s>available</s> appropriate?

A common set of permissions for `/tmp`:

```
drwxrwxrwt  root root  /tmp
```

So, available, yes, but appropriate, no, not for logs. `/tmp` is often purged on reboot.

A common set of permissions for `/var/log`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root   /var/log
```

So, it's usually only `root` processes that can create files there. Other processes need to have a logfile installed in advance and `logrotate`d - or having a subdirectory with permissions allowing the process owner to create files in it.

If your system uses [journald](https://www.google.com/search?q=journald.conf), it may be more appropriate to make use of that instead of creating your own log files as described in [Linux Logging with Systemd](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/linux-logging-with-systemd/).

*Edit: Since the original question was partly about programming languages before it was edited, I'll leave this note here:*

Whether to use syslog or not doesn't have anything to do with the choice of language. If you have a syslog service, it can be used by programs written in any language.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after I create a fold in `/var/log`, such as `/var/log/myprocess/`. Notice that `/var/log` belongs to `root`, and I use `chown` so `/var/log/myprocess/` belongs to me.

So my process can create and write files directly in `/var/log/myprocess/`, such as `/var/log/myprocess/process-log-2019-08-15.log`.

Comment: Well, that's what I wrote in my answer so I hope it didn't take too long to find that out :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo your answer is great, thanks !